# Trying to access the Passed URL from window.open()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the URL of the parsed URL from window.open. I know that may sound stupid, but I'd like to get the value of the URL after user performs a few actions.

Here is the code snippet that I have been playing around with,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("http://google.com", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + myWindow.location.href;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Can't you set the URL in a variable first and pass it to window.open?

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to get the value of the URL after user performs a few actions.

You can't. The window you've created is a cross-domain frame, so you cannot access its location.

This is necessary because the window's location may contain private information -- for instance, many older web applications will contain session IDs in the URL.